# connecting an external mongodb database to a docker container located on a different server

Tags: database, mongodb, docker

I'm having this issue where i want to connect a standalone mongoDB database to a docker container so the container can retrieve and post data in the database.

I can't use docker compose, so thats one problem. Neither can i run a mongoDB instance in a docker container.

`docker run --name user -d --cap-add NET_BIND_SERVICE --cap-drop all -e MONGO_CONNSTRING=mongodb://mongoservice:27017/users --restart always -p 80:80 --network default-net weaveworksdemos/user:0.4.4`

this is what my docker command would look like to boot up the container, but i cant seem to retrieve any data present in the database.

Does anyone see what i'm doing wrong ? or am i missing something crucial ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Normally it should be perfectly possible to access services outside of docker if the container. Is your docker host/networking maybe secured in some special way? Just start a ubuntu/debian container, `docker run -it --rm ubuntu:latest bash`, install telnet or mongodb client and try a connect / check the error message.

Comment: it might be good to note that the mongodb instance is of the version 3.4